# Resultado de única linha e coluna para coluna com várias linhas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Possuo uma função no SQL que retorna uma única linha em uma única coluna com registros separados por pontos.

Exemplo:

*Coluna 1: Resultado*

*Linha 1: 0000000.0000001.0000002.0000003.0000004.0000005.0000006*

Gostaria de inserir cada valor em uma linha separada, porém em uma única coluna.

Exemplo:

*Coluna 1: Resultado*

*Linha 1: 0000000*

*Linha 2: 0000001*

*Linha 3: 0000002*

*Linha 4: 0000003*

*Linha 5: 0000004*

*Linha 6: 0000005*

*Linha 7: 0000006*

Resumo, preciso que meu resultado de uma coluna e uma linha se transforme em uma coluna com várias linhas, mas de maneira dinâmica, pois a quantidade de registros separados por pontos (.) podem variar, ou seja, posso ter 2 registros separados por pontos, que serão 2 linhas, ou 1000 registros, que serão 1000 linhas.

Como posso proceder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Comment: Você falou "função no SQL", isso é feito pela função ou os dados são armazenados dessa forma na tabela?

Comment: @FelipeNegro Complementando a pergunta de Marconcílio, a função original é do tipo escalar ou table-valued?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza No meu BD possuo uma função (function) que retorna uma única coluna e linha. O resultado é uma string/varchar de números separados por ponto (Exemplo: 123.456.789.012 etc) e não tem tamanho específico. Neste link eu consegui obter o resultado que precisava http://zavaschi.com/index.php/2009/06/repostagem-funo-split-no-sql-server/

Comment: @JoséDiz é do tipo Escalar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Felipe, a sua solicitação contém duas das mais frequentes perguntas em fóruns de SQL: (**1**) fazer a quebra de uma cadeia de caracteres que possua vários campos separados por um delimitador (*split string*) e (**2**) transformar "uma linha / várias colunas" em "várias linhas / uma coluna" (*unpivot*).

---

Sobre a primeira parte, *split string*, há vários artigos interessantes sobre o tema, nos quais encontrará diversas soluções para o problema. Sugiro a leitura artigo “[Separar conteúdo de texto multivalorado (string split)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/01/27/separar-conteudo-de-texto-multivalorado_string-split/)”.

---

Sobre a segunda parte, *unpivot*, eis artigos sobre o assunto:

- [Use SQL Server's UNPIVOT operator to help normalize output](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3000/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-help-normalize-output/)
- [Use SQL Server's UNPIVOT operator to dynamically normalize output](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3002/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-dynamically-normalize-output/)

---

Para demonstração foi utilizada a função SplitStrings_Moden, que é derivada de uma função criada por Jeff Moden. Ela realiza o *split string* e também o *unpivot*.

O código #1 gera uma tabela temporária (variável de tabela) para simular os dados. A chamada da função de *split string* foi feita na cláusula FROM (usando cross apply), por ser uma função do tipo *table-valued*.

```
-- código #1
declare @Retorno table (ID int identity, Resultado varchar(max));

INSERT into @Retorno (Resultado) values
  ('0000000.0000001.0000002.0000003.0000004.0000005.0000006'),
  (replicate('8888888.',400) + '0000000'),
  ('0123456');

SELECT T.ID, U.Item 
  from @Retorno as T
       cross apply dbo.splitStrings_Moden(T.Resultado,'.') as U;
```

Abaixo, a transcrição do código da função SplitStrings_Moden.

```
-- código #2
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Moden
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLEfaz
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer fazer uma linha se tornar uma coluna com várias linhas, certo?

Isso se chama pivotamento (pivoting) em banco de dados e pode ser definido como mostrar os dados  que estão armazenados em linha serem mostrados em colunas.

Se esse for o caso, no SQL Server você pode usar uma query dinâmica para não ter que listar todos os campos (valores das linhas que serão convertidos em títulos de colunas) manualmente:

```html
use seu_banco_de_dados;

declare @colunas as nvarchar(max),
        @query as nvarchar(max);

select @colunas = stuff((select ',' + quotename(coluna_escolhida) 
                      from dbo.sua_tabela
                      group by coluna_escolhida
                      order by coluna_escolhida
                  for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

set @query = 'select ' + @colunas + ' from 
             (
                select valores, coluna_escolhida
                from dbo.TbFinanciamentos
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(valores)
                for coluna_escolhida in (' + @colunas + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)

--exec sp_executesql @query;
```